# Could not build module 'myFramework'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I’m building Cocoa Touch Framework in Objective C. Framework consist of some pods like SVProgressHUD and also some pods written in Swift. I’m also using use_frameworks! in my pod file.

When I compile my framework project it works fine. The problem is when I import my framework in other project it gives an error:
“Could not build module myFramework”

I tried solutions given online like to add myFramework in Embedded binaries but still getting the same error.

Can someone help me, what I’m doing wrong.
Help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you use cocoa pod for build framework?

Comment: @KamaniJasmin yes I'm using cocoa pods inside my Framework project.

Comment: One time I got this problem when i build own framework? i solve this problem by add manually framework.

Comment: could you please help me. How did you resolve it?

Comment: I say one example of SVProgressHUD.
First download SVProgressHUD project into github then open SVProgressHUD project and build it.
After build this project drag and drop [SVProgressHUD.framework] in your custome framework project then add [SVProgressHUD.framework] to Linked framework and library.
After you can add your custome framework.

Comment: I have tried with new framework project without any pods, when importing this in another project giving same error.

Comment: what are you add [SVProgressHUD.framework] or [SVProgressHUD Project swift file] ?

Comment: SVProgressHUD (Objective C classes) - Using POD

Comment: NO this is wrong way - First download SVProgressHUD project into github.
Now open SVProgressHUD project and build it.
Now find Products folder. you got SVProgressHUD.framework. then right click on SVProgressHUD.framework and drag and drop this in your framework.

Comment: Please try to understand this issues is not about SVProgressHUD. When I try my framework project without any third party lib. and after importing into a other project getting same error.

Comment: I think it will help you - http://www.yudiz.com/creating-your-own-ios-framework-and-distributed-using-cocoapods/